# Difference between "to do as much for you as" and "to do for you as much as"

Tags: meaning, word-order

In Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary 3rd ed., one of the usage examples given for the entry *much* is:

> One day I hope I'll be able **to do as much for you as** you've done for me.

Is the meaning still the same if I move the prepositional phrase *for you* just before the expression *as much as*?

> One day I hope I'll be able **to do for you as much as** you've done for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both have the same meaning. Let's simplify by replacing the noun phrase with a noun, and trimming away some of the clauses of the sentence.

> I will do a favour for you.
>
> I will do for you a favour.

Both of those are grammatically valid, and have the same meaning. The first sounds more natural, and is what most native speakers would say. The second is a valid form that you might find in a poem, folk song, old writing, or someone deliberately speaking/writing in that manner.

Comment: +1 because you're right about your example - but I don't think the preference is so marked in OP's example. In his, whichever of *for you* or *as much* comes first tends to carry more emphasis, because it's more closely associated with **do**. So there's more justification for using the second form if that's what you want to convey. But mostly it's down to context and intonation anyway.

Comment: Your basic premise is different from the OP, though your argument is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Both seem to convey the same meaning. However, the first one is more emphatic.It sounds best when "as much" is stressed.

Comment: Per my comment to @slim's answer, I agree the first tends to emphasise *as much*. But by the same token, the second tends to emphasise *for you* (i.e. - the envisaged returning of a favour *to that person* is important because of its implications for your future relationship with him - it's not just a matter of the favour being of equal value).